# I can't import materials or textures from OBJ or 3DS

Tags: materials, objects, import

I am trying to import an object and the zip file I obtained had the .OBJ plus the images that correspond to the materials, but when I import it and I go to the materials and/or textures of the object, they aren't there.

Also, I tried to import a 3DS file with its MTL, but when I open the materials window, the materials are there, with different names but they are all the same, therefore the object appears all grey.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out!

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: embedded materials are different from the blender internal or cycles material structure

Comment: Recently I have asked several questions on importing object data. Have a look at those questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Answer (score -1):

Strangely, I had a similar problem with 3DS in cycles, but was able to apply textures and materials perfectly in Blender render.

In Blender Render, I needed to play around in the materials and textures panel a little, opening one of the image files. The rest were automatically applied, but I needed to add a lamp to see it.

For Cycles, I had to open nodes and do the textures that way.

Comment: It is never a good idea to expect materials made for one render engine to work in another. While the most basic ones might work in some cases, eventually most conversion algorythms will fail, therefore the process of converting materials for use in another render engine should always be expected to include some manual work.